# How to refresh/update oData Model by new authentication?

Tags: sapui5

I have created custom offline store and want to refresh it as per new user login authentication so i want to refresh core oData model of application with new authentication to update offline store. so how can i update oData model with new authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Try this every time a user authenticates:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getModel().refresh();
```